Recovering Forgotten Bitcoin Access Through Email
Since the inception of Bitcoin, I used to earn through searches and other related activities. However, I stopped for a long time and forgot that I had Bitcoin. Can I now access it through my email?"

Bitcoin by itself does not have accounts nor can you receive or send Bitcoin by email.
You may have used a service that uses email which receives and sends Bitcoin for you, but then this would be an issue to take up with that particular service. If you do not know what service you have used, it is unlikely that you will be able to access your Bitcoin now. Furthermore, services come and go, it is possible that the service you had used no longer exists.
